# NUXT Passing data to props in dynamic endpoint

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

this is a question on NUXT and Vuex. I want to get the appropriate item in my dynamic (`_id`) page.

I have an array in my state:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  events: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Wordpress', price: 100 },
    { id: 2, name: 'VueJS', price: 200 },
    { id: 3, name: 'React', price: 300 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Angular', price: 500 },
    { id: 5, name: 'NodeJS', price: 5000 }
  ]
})
```

I have a `EventList` component that loops through the above array as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div class="event-list">
    <nuxt-link v-for="event in events" :key="event.id" :to="'/events/' + event.id">
      <EventPreview
        :id="event.id"
        :name="event.name"
        :price="event.price"
      />
    </nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

However, when I click on the `nuxt-link` it does go to the `_id` page, however... it does not pass the clicked object.

How do I get that object to the _id page? By object I mean, for example, `{ id: 1, name: 'Wordpress', price: 100 }`.

Should you need additional information (beyond what is below) please ask.

---

Additional information as follows:

Code for the `EventPreview` component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="single-event">
    <h1>Name: {{ name }}</h1>
    <h1>Price: {{ price }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'EventPreview',
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`_id` page code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="event-id">
    <EventPreview />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventPreview from '@/components/Event/EventPreview'
export default {
  components: {
    EventPreview
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a vuex store to keep the events data, and then create a getter to get the relevant event by ID.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    events: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Wordpress',
        price: 100
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'VueJS',
        price: 200
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'React',
        price: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    event: state => id => {
      return state.events.find(event => event.id === id)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  store,
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      routeId: 2
    }
  },
  computed: {
    myEvent() {
      return this.$store.getters.event(this.routeId)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>event:</h2>
  <p>Name: {{ myEvent.name }}</p>
  <p>Price: {{ myEvent.price }}</p>
</div>
```

You can then get the id from the current page route `this.$route.params.id` and pass it into the getter

```
myEvent() {
    return this.$store.getters.event(this.$route.params.id)
}
```